# Evaluating finite field elements on a separate polynomial

Tags: matlab

I'd like to construct a polynomial which will contain finite field objects (constructed with gf). The polynomial variables are not the same as in the finite field elements.
For example, for such a polynomial:

```
   g(x) = x+[0 1 0 0]
```

I'd like to be able to evaluate on x:

```
g( [1 0 1 0] ) = [1 0 1 0] + [0 1 0 0] = [1 1 1 0]
```

How can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use *@* to define an anonymous function

```
g = @(x) x + [0 1 0 0];
```

`g([1 0 1 0])` will yield `[1 1 1 0]`